# How to get process description?

Tags: c++, windows

I want to get the description of a process (the description that is seen in task manager) in Windows using C++.

Answer (score 5):

You most likely want to get the `FileDesription` field from the version resources of the main `.exe` file of the program, using the [`VerQueryValue()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winver/nf-winver-verqueryvaluea) API call.  Here is an example from that document:

> The following example shows how to enumerate the available version languages and retrieve the FileDescription string-value for each language.
>
> Be sure to call the [GetFileVersionInfoSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/api/winver/nf-winver-getfileversioninfosizea) and [GetFileVersionInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/api/winver/nf-winver-getfileversioninfoa) functions before calling **VerQueryValue** to properly initialize the *pBlock* buffer.
>
> ```
> // Structure used to store enumerated languages and code pages.
>
> HRESULT hr;
>
> struct LANGANDCODEPAGE {
>   WORD wLanguage;
>   WORD wCodePage;
> } *lpTranslate;
>
> // Read the list of languages and code pages.
>
> VerQueryValue(pBlock, 
>               TEXT("\\VarFileInfo\\Translation"),
>               (LPVOID*)&lpTranslate,
>               &cbTranslate);
>
> // Read the file description for each language and code page.
>
> for( i=0; i < (cbTranslate/sizeof(struct LANGANDCODEPAGE)); i++ )
> {
>   hr = StringCchPrintf(SubBlock, 50,
>             TEXT("\\StringFileInfo\\%04x%04x\\FileDescription"),
>             lpTranslate[i].wLanguage,
>             lpTranslate[i].wCodePage);
>   if (FAILED(hr))
>   {
>   // TODO: write error handler.
>   }
>
>   // Retrieve file description for language and code page "i". 
>   VerQueryValue(pBlock, 
>                 SubBlock, 
>                 &lpBuffer, 
>                 &dwBytes); 
> }
> ```

Comment: We can query VS_FIXEDFILEINFO using this. But that struct dont provide the description of the process. :(

Comment: Are you sure? The description in task manager appears to be the text from the "File Desription" field of the version information structure. If I'm wrong, I'll delete the answer but I was reasonable sure...

Comment: Sry I cant find the "File Desription" in VS_FIXEDFILEINFO.If you can provide a small code it would be great.I think im doing it wrong.

Comment: There is a sample at the bottom of the page I linked which extracts the value. I'm not able to try it myself at the moment though, sorry

Comment: `VS_FIXEDFILEINFO` only provides access to the File and Product version numbers.  You have to query the localized `StringFileInfo` data to access the `FileDescription`. I have added the code from the documentation to show this.

Answer (score 4):

Although I read this question, the accepted answer, and the documentation for `VerQueryValue`, I spent quite a while to understand how to use that `VerQueryValue` function (since the code example in the docs has no declarations of variables and isn't clear for me at all).

So I decided to put here the code that can be easily run as a working example of the usage of `VerQueryValue` to get a process description.

```cpp
#pragma comment(lib,"Version.lib")

#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winver.h>

using namespace std;

int printFileDescriptions(const wchar_t* filename)
{
    int versionInfoSize = GetFileVersionInfoSize(filename, NULL);
    if (!versionInfoSize) {
        return 0;
    }

    auto versionInfo = new BYTE[versionInfoSize];
    std::unique_ptr<BYTE[]> versionInfo_automatic_cleanup(versionInfo);
    if (!GetFileVersionInfo(filename, NULL, versionInfoSize, versionInfo)) {
        return 0;
    }

    struct LANGANDCODEPAGE {
        WORD wLanguage;
        WORD wCodePage;
    } *translationArray;

    UINT translationArrayByteLength = 0;
    if (!VerQueryValue(versionInfo, L"\\VarFileInfo\\Translation", (LPVOID*)&translationArray, &translationArrayByteLength)) {
        return 0;
    }

    // You may check GetSystemDefaultUILanguage() == translationArray[i].wLanguage 
    // if only the system language required
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < (translationArrayByteLength / sizeof(LANGANDCODEPAGE)); i++) {
        wchar_t fileDescriptionKey[256]; 
        wsprintf(
            fileDescriptionKey,
            L"\\StringFileInfo\\%04x%04x\\FileDescription",
            translationArray[i].wLanguage,
            translationArray[i].wCodePage
        );

        wchar_t* fileDescription = NULL;
        UINT fileDescriptionSize;
        if (VerQueryValue(versionInfo, fileDescriptionKey, (LPVOID*)&fileDescription, &fileDescriptionSize)) {
            wcout << endl << fileDescription << endl;
        }
    }

    return TRUE;
}

int main()
{
    // Set locale of the console to print non-ASCII symbols
    SetConsoleOutputCP(GetACP());
    SetConsoleCP(GetACP());
    wcout.imbue(std::locale("")); // set default global locale
    // ----------------------------------------------------

    auto path = L"C:\\Windows\\explorer.exe";
    printFileDescriptions(path);

    wcin.get(); // to prevent console close
}
```

It's supposed that all WinAPI functions on your system use `wchar_t`, that is `VerQueryValueW` is actually used.

The initial version of the code I took here [Retrieve File Description an Application VerQueryValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53123914/retrieve-file-description-an-application-verqueryvalue)