# Where can i find library "version.lib" in order to successfully call GetFileVersionInfoSize()?

Tags: c++, mingw, static-libraries, mingw-w64, dev-c++

I'm developing a project on **DevC++** which uses **MinGW64**. On Windows 7 (i don't know if this can be related to my issue).

I had a problem compiling a **C++** program where I call the function `GetFileVersionInfoSize()`, which is:

> main.cpp:(.text+0x51): undefined reference to `GetFileVersionInfoSizeA'

After two days of researching, I understood that I have to include in the parameters of the linker the **"version.lib"** file, which is missing in my computer, I searched it everywhere.
I can't even find a download mirror on the web, so I'm asking, **does anybody know where I can find version.lib?** Maybe somewhere hidden in my PC or in the web? Maybe with a new installation of MinGW64? I don't know, since my installation of MinGW64 came with DevC++.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Maybe not helpful, but the name of the file is `Version.lib` (note uppercase V) - this *may* make a difference (but shouldn't for searching on Windows). May affect MinGW64, though?

Comment: @AdrianMole thanks for making me notice that, even if it's minor. Searching on Windows with uppercase V didn't help of course. At this point it's more like a research on the web for a download.

Comment: As MinGW64 uses the Unix nameing convention for libraries it will be called something starting with `libversion` and your linker command should include `-lversion`

Comment: But I'm amazed that MingW64 doesn't have this core file! I just searched my HD and even `Borland C Version 5` (I use that for testing code compatibility) has it, as does `WatCom C`. You could try installing a Windows SDK - I think MinGW can work with these.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a environment built for *GCC*, library names will follow *Nix* conventions:

- Start with *lib*: *libversion*
- Extension can be either *.so* or *.a* (depending on the library being dynamic or static)

Typically (depending on default *MinGW* installation), it should reside in *${MINGW_INSTALL_DIR}/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/**libversion.a***. 
One installation example is: *f:\Install\Qt\Qt\Tools\mingw730_64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libversion.a*.

According to [[Archive.Web - MinGW]: HOWTO Specify the Location of Libraries for use with MinGW](http://web.archive.org/web/20200116052117/http://www.mingw.org/wiki/LibraryPathHOWTO) (*Determining MinGW's Default Library Search Path* section), it can be retrieved by:

```bash
[cfati@cfati-5510-0:/cygdrive/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow]> x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld.exe --verbose | grep SEARCH_DIR | tr -s ' ;' \\012
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib")
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib")
SEARCH_DIR("=/lib")
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib")
```

But since it's a *system library*, you shouldn't care about its path, *MinGW* should find it automatically, all you have to do is pass it to the linker (using the standard ways).

Comment: Yes, I found it, but the result was the same of when I tried to include the .dll file `version.dll`. When I run the program, a popup displays *"main.exe has stopped working"*. I also tried with -lversion such as @RichardCritten said, but same thing happened.

Comment: Then that's the next step. Since you managed to run your program, it means that it was successfully built, which I think was the purpose of the question.  When running, make sure *${MINGW_INSTALL_DIR}/bin* is in *%PATH%*.

Comment: Open a *cmd* terminal, in the dir where your built executable is located, type `set PATH=%PATH%;${MINGW_INSTALL_DIR}/bin` (obviously *${MINGW\_INSTALL\_DIR}* is just a placeholder for your installation directory), then run your executable from that terminal.

Comment: Do I need double quotes for *${MINGW_INSTALL_DIR}*? I'm **very** unexperienced. And it's 2am tho.

Comment: No need for quoutes, don't forget the *\bin* at the end.

Comment: Well, just done it. Nothing changed :( Thanks anyway, any ideas?

Comment: Without some minimal code (and steps) to reproduce (and some tools versions), no.

Answer (score 0):

**Thank all you guys for the suggestions you gave me**

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59557289/12637994) answer there is how to find *Version.lib* in this case.

The following is about accomplishing using `GetFileVersionInfoSize()`, `GetFileVersionInfo()` and `VerQueryValue()` to get the **Product Name** of an executable file, which is why I needed *Version.lib*, actually being called *libversion.a* on my machine.

**LAST-EDIT:** I managed to achieve what I wanted, this is the code that works in my case:

```
// filename contains the path of the .exe we want to get Product Name
int version_info_size = GetFileVersionInfoSize(filename, NULL);

if(version_info_size > 0) {
    BYTE *version_info_buffer = new BYTE[version_info_size];

    if(GetFileVersionInfo(filename, 0, version_info_size, version_info_buffer)) {
        char *product_name = NULL;
        UINT pLenFileInfo = 0;

        if(VerQueryValue(version_info_buffer,  TEXT("\\StringFileInfo\\040904e4\\ProductName"),
        (LPVOID*)&product_name, &pLenFileInfo)) cout << product_name;
    }
}
```

Notice that if you want to compare `product_name` with another value, you have to do something like `string product_name_str = product_name` and compare that string variable, otherwise the comparison will always return **false**. Or maybe just do `(string)product_name`, I should try.

`040904e4` is the lang-code hex translation that I needed in order to do this, I found it thanks to the code in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53125003/12637994) answer.