# How to retrieve audio session name similar to one in Windows' built-in mixer app?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm building a mixer app and need to get the user-friendly names for each audio session.

I tried:

1. `IAudioSessionControl::GetDisplayName()` method, but it returned empty string for each session.
2. Calling `QueryFullProcessImageName()` and `GetModuleFileNameEx()`, but they only output `C:\Users\` since I have Cyrillic letters in the path. But even if they did output the full path, I assume it would end with something like `...\brave.exe` (correct me if I'm wrong), which is not a user-friendly name like `Brave Browser` in Windows' built-in mixer.
3. I also tried getting all process names and PIDs like this, and later match them to session process IDs, which successfully gave me names like `chrome.exe` or `steam.exe`, but they are still, again, not quite what I want:

   ```cpp
   std::vector<std::pair<DWORD, wchar_t*>> processes;

       HANDLE handle = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
       PROCESSENTRY32 entry;
       entry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

       Process32First(handle, &entry);
       do {
           processes.emplace_back(entry.th32ProcessID, entry.szExeFile);
       } while (Process32Next(handle, &entry));

       CloseHandle(handle);
   ```

What I want is to retrieve names like in the built-in mixer app, ie `Steam`, `Chrome Browser`, `Zoom Meetings`, etc.

Is there a way to achieve this? Or does Microsoft use some kind of black magic here?

Comment: Seems like you want to get the process main HWND (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888863/how-to-get-main-window-handle-from-process-id) and then use `GetWindowText` on it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Calling `QueryFullProcessImageName()` and `GetModuleFileNameEx()`, but they only output `C:\Users\` since I have Cyrillic letters in the path.

Then you are simply not displaying the path correctly. The presence of Cyrillic characters is not a problem.

> I also tried getting all process names and PIDs like this, and later match them to session process IDs, which successfully gave me names like `chrome.exe` or `steam.exe`, but they are still, again, not quite what I want

That code doesn't work properly. You are storing pointers in your `std::vector` that point to a single `wchar_t[]` buffer which is modified on each loop iteration. You should instead store `std::wstring` instead of `wchar_t*` so each path is copied.

> What I want is to retrieve names like in the built-in mixer app, ie `Steam`, `Chrome Browser`, `Zoom Meetings`, etc.

Once you have the path to the EXE, you can use `GetFileVersionInfo()` and `VerQueryValue()` to retrieve the app's human-readable `FileDescription`. See [Retrieve File Description for an Application using VerQueryValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53123914/).

Comment: Are you the God himself? Thanks, that worked like a charm!